# Which one should be chosen?

Tags: word-choice

> Accountants help people with their
>    1. Finance
>    2. Finances

Comment: Unlike the previous post of yours, this question is going to get closed because it lacks any effort and any research on your part. The title is also too generic and meaningless to visitors. Please say why you are confused and which answer you think is best, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finance is a field, Example: I studied finance

So you cannot use that with the sentence you have mentioned, 
Accountants help people with their finance  - Wrong Because Finance is a course.

Instead, use Finances, Accountants help people with their Finances - Correct Because finances refers to the business/individual.

Comment: So which one is right?

Comment: Finances, this is the correct word for the sentence he has mentioned

Comment: Please [**edit your answer**](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/496723/edit) to explain which word is correct and why.